# inodes & read only bind mount

Tags: mount, xfs

I'm using `xfs` filesystem, speaking about inodes topic have a question: **does `RO` bind mount points consumes inodes?**

The *information* is the same, strictly speaking; because the binds mounts point to a directory in the same filesystem.

With `df -i` is possible to see tha inodes consumption, well.

Comment: Your question is unclear, and would probably be a better fit on Unix/Linux StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

Files in the bound directory have exactly the same inode as the original. So no, it doesn't consume anything.

But you could have made the test yourself :

```
root@storiq-nas10:/mnt/raid# df -i .
Sys. de fichiers         In?uds IUtil.     ILibre IUti% Monté sur
/dev/mapper/vg0-raid 7497565248    107 7497565141    1% /mnt/raid
root@storiq-nas10:/mnt/raid# mount -B test/ bind/
root@storiq-nas10:/mnt/raid# df -i .
Sys. de fichiers         In?uds IUtil.     ILibre IUti% Monté sur
/dev/mapper/vg0-raid 7497565248    107 7497565141    1% /mnt/raid
root@storiq-nas10:/mnt/raid# cd bind/dir/hello/
root@storiq-nas10:/mnt/raid/bind/dir/hello# ls -i 34.txt 
4294967458 34.txt
root@storiq-nas10:/mnt/raid/bind/dir/hello# cd /mnt/raid/test/dir/hello/
root@storiq-nas10:/mnt/raid/test/dir/hello# ls -i 34.txt 
4294967458 34.txt
```